# How to get count of unpublished commit with GitPython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

With `git status` I can get information about count of unpublished commits:

```
» git status             
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I want to get unpublished commits (or count) with GitPython. I docs I found `repo.git.status()`, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
repo.iter_commits('BRANCH@{u}..BRANCH')
```

or if you want this as a list:

```
list(repo.iter_commits('BRANCH@{u}..BRANCH'))
```

The `BRANCH@{u}` syntax refers to the upstream branch of `BRANCH`.

Comment: This gave me an empty list, when I knew that I had unpushed changes. I found that I had to reverse the order of arguments, to find commits that I had made locally but not yet pushed, for example this worked: `list(repo.iter_commits('master@{u}..master'))`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Chronial and @Clare-Macrae for your feedback
Using [`gitPython`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/) `==3.1.11`, I did it like that:

```py
branch = self.repo.active_branch
unpushed_symbol = '⇡' if list(self.repo.iter_commits(f'{branch}@{{u}}..{branch}')) else constants.NOTHING
unpulled_symbol = '⇣' if list(self.repo.iter_commits(f'{branch}..{branch}@{{u}}')) else constants.NOTHING
```