# Check status of local Python relative to remote with GitPython

Tags: python, git

How can I use [GitPython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/0.3.2.RC1) to determine whether:

- My local branch is ahead of the remote (I can safely push)
- My local branch is behind the remote (I can safely pull)
- My local branch has diverged from the remote?

To check if the local and remote are the same, I'm doing this:

```
def local_and_remote_are_at_same_commit(repo, remote):
    local_commit = repo.commit()
    remote_commit = remote.fetch()[0].commit
    return local_commit.hexsha == remote_commit.hexsha
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get count of unpublished commit with GitPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849640/how-to-get-count-of-unpublished-commit-with-gitpython)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15862203/197789

E.g.

```py
commits_behind = repo.iter_commits('master..origin/master')
```

and

```py
commits_ahead = repo.iter_commits('origin/master..master')
```

Then you can use something like the following to go from iterator to a count:

```py
count = sum(1 for c in commits_ahead)
```

(You may want to fetch from the remotes before running `iter_commits`, eg: `repo.remotes.origin.fetch()`)

This was last checked with GitPython 1.0.2.

Comment: With a branch that was 3 commits behind and 1 commit ahead, this gave me a sum of 4 for `len(list(commits_behind))` and `len(list(commits_ahead))`

Answer (score 2):

The following worked better for me, which I got from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940027/448679)

```
commits_diff = repo.git.rev_list('--left-right', '--count', f'{branch}...{branch}@{{u}}')
num_ahead, num_behind = commits_diff.split('\t')
print(f'num_commits_ahead: {num_ahead}')
print(f'num_commits_behind: {num_behind}')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what's @{{u}}???

Comment: I believe it's for "upstream", the double `{` is to escape the python string formatter `{`