# git ahead/behind info between master and branch?

Tags: git, github

I have created a branch for testing in my local repo (`test-branch`) which I pushed to `Github`.

If I go to my `Github` account and select this `test-branch` it shows the info:

```
This branch is 1 commit ahead and 2 commits behind master
```

My questions are:

1. How can I display this info locally (ie: a command that shows this on the terminal, rather than having to open `Github` to see it)?
2. I know I can see the diffs between branches using:

   ```
   git diff master..test-branch
   ```

   or using `Meld` (which I prefer):

   ```
   git difftool master..test-branch
   ```

   but I was wondering if there's a way to see the *ahead* and *behind* commits separately. I.E.: is there a way to show that *1 commit ahead* by itself and then those *2 commits behind* by themselves?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163803/alias-that-displays-how-many-commits-branches-are-ahead-behind-master

Comment: Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015) will introduce `git for-each-ref --format="%(push:track)" refs/heads`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30720338/6309)

Comment: Because I couldn't find this question using the keywords I'm about to write, I just want to note that this amounts to taking the [*relative complement* (or "set difference")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) between the sets of commits that make up those branches (and then counting the elements). Hopefully this makes it into search engine indices.

Comment: Very helpful!  For help in finding this via search engines, I'll add an example where both numbers are plural: `This branch is 164 commits ahead, 85 commits behind master.`

Answer (score 461, accepted):

### Part 1

As an answer on your question 1, here's a trick I found to compare two branches and show how many commits each branch is ahead of the other (a more general answer on your question 1):

For **local** branches:
`git rev-list --left-right --count master...test-branch`

For **remote** branches:
`git rev-list --left-right --count origin/master...origin/test-branch`

This gives output like the following:

`2       1`

This output means: "Compared to `master`, `test-branch` is 1 commit ahead and 2 commits behind."

You can also compare local branches with remote branches, e.g. `origin/master...master` to find out how many commits a local branch (here `master`) is ahead/behind its remote counterpart.

### Part 2

To answer the second part of your question, the solution depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

**To view commits**

In order to have `git rev-list` return the exact list of commits unique on either side, replace the `--count` argument with something like `--pretty=oneline`, making the complete command to execute:

```sh
git rev-list --left-right --pretty=oneline master...test-branch
```

This will generate output like this:

```
<bba27b56ad7072e281d529d4845e4edf877eb7d7 unique commit 2 on master
<dad0b69ec50ea57b076bfecabf2cc7c8a652bb6f unique commit 1 on master
>4bfad52fbcf0e60d78d06661d5c06b59c98ac8fd unique commit 1 on test-branch
```

Here every commit sha is preceded by `<` or `>` to indicate which branch it can be found on (left or right, here `master` or `test-branch` respectively).

**To view code**

If you want to view a diff of all new commits only found on either branch, you'll need to do this in two steps:

1. define the most recent common ancestor

```sh
$ git merge-base master test-branch
c22faff7468d6d5caef217ac6b82f3ed95e9d902
```

2. diff either branch to the commit sha obtained above (short format will usually do)

To show the diff of all commits only found on master

```sh
git diff c22faff7..master
```

To show the diff of all commits only found test-branch

```sh
git diff c22faff7..test-branch
```

Comment: This is a great solution for me to find out if i can delete a branch or if it is still ahead of develop.

Comment: @Maverick1st, yes, this command is particularly useful when you are following the [gitflow workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (which I am)

Comment: This is the best for my use case of finding if your current feature branch is behind remote master (`git rev-list --left-right --count origin/master...@`) - provided the user does `git fetch` before; useful to prevent pull requests from outdated branches.

Comment: To check just how many commits *behind* is the current branch:
`git rev-list --left-right --count origin/master...@ | cut -f1`

Comment: @jakub.g you don't need to cut if you use `--left-only` or `--right-only`

Comment: Am trying to add this info to cmd prompt using something like 
# add ahead/behind info between remote and local
function git_is_branch_pushed {
  REMOTE_TO_LOCAL=`git rev-list --left-right --count origin/$1...$1 2> /dev/null`
  LOCAL_TO_REMOTE=`git rev-list --left-right --count origin/$1...$1 2> /dev/null`
  if [[ ${REMOTE_TO_LOCAL} != ${LOCAL_TO_REMOTE} ]]; then
    echo -ne "R: ${REMOTE_TO_LOCAL} L:${LOCAL_TO_REMOTE}"
  fi
}
BRANCH=`git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/\1/"`
git_is_branch_pushed ${BRANCH}


and its not functioning as expected.

Comment: This solution also works for the current commit, not just for branches. Example: check out the commit 26 behind master: `git checkout master~26` then run `git rev-list --left-right --count master...@` and you'll see `26     0`.

Comment: For checking if your current local branch is behind the same branch upstream use: `git rev-list --left-right --count "@{u}...@"`.

Answer (score 64):

First of all to see how many revisions you are behind locally, you should do a `git fetch` to make sure you have the latest info from your remote.

The default output of `git status` tells you how many revisions you are ahead or behind, but usually I find this too verbose:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 2 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I prefer `git status -sb`:

```
$ git status -sb
## master...origin/master [ahead 2, behind 1]
```

In fact I alias this to simply `git s`, and this is the main command I use for checking status.

To see the diff in the "ahead revisions" of `master`, I can exclude the "behind revisions" from `origin/master`:

```
git diff master..origin/master^
```

To see the diff in the "behind revisions" of `origin/master`, I can exclude the "ahead revisions" from `master`:

```
git diff origin/master..master^^
```

If there are 5 revisions ahead or behind it might be easier to write like this:

```
git diff master..origin/master~5
git diff origin/master..master~5
```

**UPDATE**

To see the ahead/behind revisions, the branch must be configured to track another branch. For me this is the default behavior when I clone a remote repository, and after I push a branch with `git push -u remotename branchname`. My version is 1.8.4.3, but it's been working like this as long as I remember.

As of version 1.8, you can set the tracking branch like this:

```
git branch --track test-branch
```

As of version 1.7, the syntax was different:

```
git branch --set-upstream test-branch
```

Comment: What version of `git` are you using? I can't reproduce what you get with either `git status` nor with `git status -sb`. If I try either command (after doing `git fetch`) I do not get any info on commits ahead/behind.

Comment: Your way to see commits ahead and behind is applied to `master` and `origin/master` and I want to see those diffs for `master` and a another branch `test-branch`. Could you reformat your answer address this issue?

Comment: The diff in "behind" and "ahead" revisions only works for me if I use 3 dots between the branch names (not 2). And the ^ and ^^ didn't seem to matter here E.g.:
git diff master...origin/master
git diff origin/master...master

Anyways, "git status -sb" was very helpful.

Answer (score 17):

With Git 2.5+, you now have another option to see ahead/behind for all branches which are configured to push to a branch.

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(push:track)" refs/heads
```

See more at "[Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720302/6309)", which illustrates, for instance, how you may want to know which commits you haven't pushed yet:

```
git log @{push}..
```

Comment: Could you do this for just the current branch and its remote tracking branch?

Comment: @spex yes: complete `refs/heads` with the name of the current branch (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142066/6309): `refs/heads/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`

Comment: @RickyLevi Good point, I have edited the answer to make that option more visible.

Answer (score 6):

To get the number of commits ahead of master for your current feature branch you can use the following command:

```sh
git rev-list --left-right --count master...$(git branch --show-current)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `awk` to make it a little bit prettier:

```
git rev-list --left-right --count  origin/develop...feature-branch | awk '{print "Behind "$1" - Ahead "$2""}'
```

You can even make an alias that always fetches origin first and then compares the branches

```
commit-diff = !"git fetch &> /dev/null && git rev-list --left-right --count"
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing a git fetch, you can run git status to show how many commits the local branch is ahead or behind of the remote version of the branch.

This won't show you how many commits it is ahead or behind of a different branch though. Your options are the full diff, looking at github, or using a solution like Vimhsa linked above: [Git status over all repo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757843/git-status-over-all-repos/18760795#18760795)