# Will Git tell you if you are behind your remote repo?

Tags: git, version-control

When working in a repo, Git will display a message when calling `git status` that your ahead of `origin/branchName` by x amount of commits. But if the remote repository was updated for example, by someone else on another computer and they `push`, so I am actually **behind** the remote repository. Will calling `git status` notify me of this?

Comment: `git status` only tells you where you are relative to `origin` based on the last time it checked origin (via fetch or push).  So no, `git status` alone will not notify you of this.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` followed by `git status` will tell you if are behind on your current branch if it tracks a remote branch. Running `git fetch` won't touch any local refs, and you can use `--dry-run` if you are paranoid about what it will do.

This is possibly a duplicate of [git ahead/behind info between master and branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433867/git-ahead-behind-info-between-master-and-branch)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `git fetch` that means pulling only information of the remote repository.