# Git - Show number of commits behind upstream

Tags: git, github

Our teams tend to not keep track of how many commits they are behind the latest released code. We want to notify them of that, but getting the information is the hard part, the notify part is done.

What I would like to understand how to pull the git log down, do a git command that outputs "Branch x is behind branch y by 5 commits". I don't want to have to checkout the branch as it pulls down our 600mb+ repo each time for all of our branches, plus I'm running low on drive space. I have found similar questions on stack overflow that reference bash scripts that only work locally, or the ones that point to remote return blank. I'm still learning git and bash, please bear with me.

Comment: Try `git fetch` then `git branch -vv`

Comment: Tried that just now, blank response.
git fetch http://{github url}
"From http://{github}
* branch      HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD

git branch -vv

Comment: What version of git are you using?  Are you using tracking branches?

Comment: **See Also**: [git ahead/behind info between master and branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20433867/1366033)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is `git rev-list` (reverse chronological order of commits).

After cloning a repo (make sure the remote is set and `git fetch origin` has been performed), to get ahead number of the branch from master, try

`git rev-list origin/master..origin/feature/SuperCoolBranch --count`

switch the branches around to find out the behind number.

Comment: This should work with current branch, should it? `git rev-list HEAD..origin --count`

Comment: Yes, what you mentioned should work on current branch.

Comment: Is there really no way to do this without having to actually retrieve the entire remote branch?

Comment: @Neutrino, no there is not. Git doesn't store metadata, so queries require consideration of all the historical commits in question, and there is no existing built in mechanism to query this information on a remote repository.