# This branch is 4 commits ahead, 73 commits behind working

Tags: git

I know, that this question is asked several times, but I decided to ask too, because I need also advice what to do in order this not to happen in the future....

Since several months I am working on a project. For every new functionality a feature branch is created, then when I am ready, the feature branch is merged into the "working" branch, which is deployed on the test environments. And when we decide to do a release, I merge to the "master" branch via pull request in GitHub and I use the "Squash and merge" option. But obviously this is wrong, because now every time when I create a pull request, all the commits are listed.
So

1. How to solve this issue? From this answer:
   [GitHub keeps saying "This branch is X commits ahead, Y commits behind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283955/github-keeps-saying-this-branch-is-x-commits-ahead-y-commits-behind)

I assume I have to do the following:

```
git checkout master
git pull working master
git push origin master
```

Is that correct?
2.Which option for merging I have to use in the future, in order this not to happen again?
The other options are:

"Create a merge commit - all commits from this branch will be added to the base branch via merge commit"

and
"Rebase and merge - the 73 commits from this branch will be rebased and added to the base branch"

Comment: Don't blindly run `git pull` and `git push` just because this is how some dumb tutorial taught you. Don't run `git pull` at all, unless you know **exactly** what it does. Read about and practice [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) and [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) and use a graphical Git client to **see** what they do.

Comment: *Which option for merging I have to use in the future, in order this not to happen again?* First and foremost, never, *never* *ever*, use squash-and-merge. That doesn't mean that you never get into problems anymore. But at least the problems can be resolved in more user-friendly ways.