# Why do GitHub and the git command line give different results for merge status & commits ahead/behind?

Tags: git, github

When I run

```
git branch --no-merged
```

on [this repo](https://github.com/CDLUC3/mrt-dashboard), the first listed branch is one called [dcxl](https://github.com/CDLUC3/mrt-dashboard/tree/dcxl).

But when I view the branch in GitHub, what I see is just

> This branch is 1291 commits behind master.

And when I go to GitHub’s pull request interface, I get:

> **There isn’t anything to compare.**
>
> **master** is up to date with all commits from dcxl.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940027/27358), the way to see commits ahead/behind is

```
git rev-list --left-right --count [BRANCH]...master
```

When I run this, I get:

```
$ git rev-list --left-right --count master...dcxl
426     1717
```

I read this as “Branch `dcxl` is 426 commits ahead, 1717 commits behind master.”

Now, 1717 - 426 = 1291, so there’s clearly some relationship between the `git rev-list` output and what GitHub’s telling me, but GitHub seems to be somehow identifying those 426 “ahead” commits with 426 of the 1717 “behind” commits in a way that `git rev-list` doesn’t.

From some answer, I’m not sure which, I found the `--no-merges` option, and tried that, in case merge commits were the difference:

```
$ git rev-list --left-right --count --no-merges dcxl...master
396     1610
```

Still different.

I have other repos where the `git rev-list` output exactly matches GitHub’s. And this particular repo, including branches, was migrated from Mercurial, so there could be all kinds of shenanigans in the history. But I'm pretty sure GitHub is right, here, and there's nothing in this branch that needs merging.

But how can I check that from the command line? Why are the numbers I'm getting different, and what commands / options would I need to get the same numbers GitHub is giving me?

Comment: In a comment below the linked answer, someone recommended runing  `git rev-list --left-right --count origin/master...@ | cut -f1` to get _behinds_, did you try that ? what does it output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you are getting the results you are getting, but it clearly has something to do with the fact that you have *your own* branches.  I just cloned the repository myself, and this is what I get:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/CDLUC3/mrt-dashboard
Cloning into 'mrt-dashboard'...
remote: Counting objects: 23264, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (142/142), done.
remote: Total 23264 (delta 103), reused 127 (delta 56), pack-reused 23066
Receiving objects: 100% (23264/23264), 121.78 MiB | 3.51 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9203/9203), done.
$ cd mrt-dashboard/
$ git rev-list --left-right --count origin/dcxl...origin/master
0       1291
```

Note that I do not have a branch named `dcxl`.  I do have (my own) `master`, as my `git clone` ended by doing a `git checkout master` which created my `master` using `origin/master`, so that they both point to the same commit:

```
$ git rev-parse master origin/master
4c8616fe9b6eb3d3ea113c07ab307cfb78247c5e
4c8616fe9b6eb3d3ea113c07ab307cfb78247c5e
```

You obviously must have your own `dcxl` that points to some commit other than the one to which `origin/dcxl` points:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/dcxl
f866dd35916bc7b8154441dce53c76d20b166c37
```

#### There are many ways your own repository may be out of sync with another

Remember, every name is simply a human-readable name for some Git hash ID.  Branch names have a few special features, including these two:

- they only ever point to *commit* objects, and
- Git knows that it is OK to "move" a branch name using a fast-forward operation.

Remote-tracking names like `origin/dcxl` share these features with branch names.

What the latter means is that if you ask Git to update a branch name whose current hash is H<sub>old</sub> so that its new hash is H<sub>new</sub>, Git will check whether H<sub>old</sub> is an ancestor of H<sub>new</sub>.  If so, that update is a fast-forward.  If not, the requested update is a non-fast-forward: it may still be allowed (depending on how you asked for it), but making the change might lose commits.

If you are on some branch and run `git merge commit-specifier`, for any valid commit specifier—see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for all the ways to spell a commit—Git will check to see if the change can be done as a fast-forward.  If so, Git will update your index and work-tree and do the fast-forward on the branch name.  This is not a merge at all!  But if the operation cannot be done as a fast-forward, Git will go through the process of merging, and if that succeeds, make a *merge commit* to remember both the previously-current commit and the commit that you just merged.  This is a true merge.

Your own branch names like `dcxl` may therefore not correspond to `origin/name` remote-tracking names, either because you have not done a fast-forward, or because you did a merge that was not a fast-forward.  Or you may even have a combination of these: some merge(s) and/or fast-forwards done, but your branch name remains behind another.

Alternatively, or in addition, the other Git repository may have had its branch names rudely shoved about in non-fast-forward fashion.  In this case you may have commits on your local branch that are no longer reachable from the current value of the remote-tracking name.

(And, of course, it's important to run `git fetch` first.  This updates your own remote-tracking names to remember what the current values of the branch names are, as stored in the Git repository on GitHub.  You will see, at this time, which remote-tracking names are being fast-forwarded, and which are being force-updated instead.  This point is a bit subtle, even though `git fetch` actually displays it three ways (!).)

Comment: This is it. If I run `git rev-list --left-right --count origin/dcxl...master` I get `0 1291`.