# Check if a git branch is ahead of another using a script

Tags: linux, git, scripting, git-branch

I have `branch1` and `branch2` and I want some sort of:

`git branch1 isahead branch2`

That will show if `branch1` has commits that `branch2` doesn't have (and possibly specify those commits too). I can't check diff cause `branch2` **is** ahead of `branch1` (has commits that branch1 doesn't have).

Is there a way? I looked through `git diff` and couldn't find anything

Comment: I think the term 'ahead' or 'behind' only applies to comparing a local branch to remote one. I'm not sure it makes sense to use the term comparing two branches as the could have completely different histories.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use

`git log branch2..branch1`

If `branch1` has no commit ahead of `branch2`, output will be empty.

You can also use `git rev-list --count branch2..branch1`

This will show the number of commits ahead

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433867/git-ahead-behind-info-between-master-and-branch)

Comment: Both are great - Second one is more script appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: `--right-only` (or any of the related options) is only useful with the three-dot symmetric difference syntax. Here, it has no effect and can simply be omitted.

Comment: Thanks torek, I edited the answer according to your remark ;)

Answer (score 7):

[matthiasbe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51475693/1256452) is fine for many purposes, but for scripting, as long as your Git is not too severely ancient,<sup>1</sup>, you would generally want to use:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor commit-specifier-1 commit-specifier-2; then
    # commit specifier #1 is an ancestor of commit specifier 2
else
    # commit specifier #1 is NOT an ancestor of commit specifier 2
fi
```

as the test.  This is because `git merge-base --is-ancestor` encodes the result as its exit status, so that you do not have to run a separate test to compare the number to something.

Note that it is possible for one branch tip to be both ahead of *and* behind another:

```
$ git rev-list --left-right --count stash-exp...master
1       6473
```

Here, *neither* specified commit is an ancestor of the other.  However, given these other specifiers:

```
$ git rev-list --left-right --count master...origin/master
0       103
```

we see that `master` here is strictly behind `origin/master`, so that:

```
$ git merge-base --is-ancestor master origin/master && echo can fast-forward
can fast-forward
```

which is the same answer you would get from seeing the zero count out of `git rev-list --count origin/master..master`:

```
$ git rev-list --count origin/master..master
0
```

---

<sup>1</sup>`git merge-base --is-ancestor` was introduced in Git version 1.8.0.  Some systems are still shipping with Git 1.7...

Answer (score 4):

You have already got an answer. So I'll add something more.

`git cherry` command can be used to do this.

```
git cherry branch1 branch2
```

This will list the commits which are in `branch2`, but not in `branch1`. You can use the -v flag to make it print the commit message along with the hash if you want.

```
git cherry -v branch1 branch2
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry

Hope it helps :)