# Why does 'git rev-list --left-right' comparing A..B not consistent with B..A?

Tags: git

I am trying to compare two commits to get their Ahead/Behind differences using the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940027/1949430

"git rev-list --left-right --count A..B" where A and B are each SHA1 commit references.

In one case, a comparison of A..B gives 0 Ahead and 17 Behind.  If I re-run the same command for B..A, then I get 0 Ahead and 0 Behind, whereas I'd expect it to be the simple inverse of 17 Ahead and 0 Behind.  In another case I get 0/6 in one direction and 0/2 in the other. This defeats my purpose of trying to better visualize the differences, in this case of a submodule reference vs checked out commit.

Why do I get entirely different results for A..B than I do for B..A?   I need/expect to get a consistent value regardless of the order, with simply the ahead vs behind counts being swapped...

Is there a better way of consistently getting this information?  At present, the only solution I see is to run the command twice in a script (one for each direction) and display whichever value is greater.

Comment: How about doing it with `--graph --oneline` instead of `--count`  to see what's being counted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: you want `git rev-list --left-right --count A...B`.  Note *three* dots, not *two*.

The two-dot notation means<sup>1</sup> *commits reachable from `B`, minus any commits reachable from `A`*.  Suppose there are 17 such commits because the revision history looks like this:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- A
            \
             o--o--o--...--o   <-- B (17 commits in total, 13 not shown here)
```

All commits on the top row are reachable from `A` so they get subtracted away from the set of commits reachable from `B` (both rows).  That leaves the 17 that you get counted.

Swapping the order means *commits reachable from `A`, minus any commits reachable from `B`.*  Since all commits are reachable from `B`, we subtract them from the set of commits reachable from `A`, leaving no commits at all.  The count is therefore zero.

The *three*-dot notation `A...B` means<sup>2</sup> *commits reachable from **either** `A` **or** `B`, minus all commits reachable from **both** `A` **and** `B`.*  In the diagram above, there are 17 commits reachable from `B` but not `A`, and zero commits reachable from `A` and not `B`.  Using `--left-right` splits them into their sub-groups; using `--count` counts them; putting both together gets you the two numbers, and the two numbers will take the left or right position depending on whether you use `A...B` or `B...A`.

The three-dot notation is more useful in a graph that looks like:

```
       o--o   <-- A
      /
...--*
      \
       o--o--o   <-- B
```

Here there are two commits reachable from `A` but not `B`, and three commits reachable from `B` but not `A`.  All the middle-row commits `*` and earlier are reachable from both tips and hence excluded by the three-dot notation.

---

<sup>1</sup>For `git diff`, the two and three dot notations mean something very different.  The diff commands mostly demand just *two* commits, and `A..B` or `A...B` quite often mean *many* commits—more than the two that `git diff` likes—so `git diff A..B` just means: *use `A` as the left side and `B` as the right*, which is exactly the same thing as `git diff A B`.  That's not really all that useful, since you could have replaced the two dots with a space yourself, but that *is* what it means.

<sup>2</sup>In `git diff`, the three-dot syntax takes on a new and very different (and useful!) meaning.  Instead of comparing commits `A` and `B`, the `A...B` notation means: *Find the excluded commit in the middle*—this is, more or less, the merge base—*and use that as the left side.  Use `B` as the right side.*  For the last case illustrated above, the excluded commit in the middle is commit `*`, which really is the merge base.  So `git diff A...B` means *diff commit `*` vs commit `B`*, while `git diff B...A` means *diff commit `*` vs commit `A`*.

---

#### Sidebar: an easy way to think about this

For those who are visually-oriented, imagine you have a printed version of the graph and two different colored highlighting markers, red and green.  You take the graph, such as:

```
       o--o   <-- A
      /
...--*
      \
       o--o--o   <-- B
```

You take your *red* highlighting marker and mark the commit to which `A` points.  Then, follow the backwards connectors from that commit to its parent(s).  Mark those red too.  Keep moving backwards until everything you can get to this way—by moving backwards, through all parent commits at any merges—is marked red.

Then, take your *green* highlighting marker and mark the commit to which `B` points.  Follow this one backwards to its parent(s), and mark those green.  Keep marking green until everything you can get to this way is marked green.

Any commits with *only* green highlighting are included.  Any commits with red or both highlighting are excluded.  What you have really done here is set subtraction, of the two sets of *reachable* commits, but it's easy to think about.

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks for the speedy reply and detailed explanation.