# How to check how many commits my branch is away from master

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to to check how many commits away from master, regardless of how many other commits have been pushed to master since I branched off.

What's the right git command to do that

```
----(x)----(master)-----(a)-----(latest master)
              \
               \
               (branch_awesome/c)----(d)-----(e)
```

In this example I am three commits away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git ahead/behind info between master and branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433867/git-ahead-behind-info-between-master-and-branch)

Comment: yes. It does____________________________