# How to list branches in git with the number of commits ahead or behind master?

Tags: git, github

I really like how the Github /branches page lists the branches and a column that indicates the number of commits ahead or behind master for a branch.

Is there a way to see this information in the console/cli?

Edit: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940027/1830563) shows how to get the commits ahead/behind for a single branch. But how could I do that for all local branches?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git ahead/behind info between master and branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433867/git-ahead-behind-info-between-master-and-branch)

Comment: @flaxel kind of, that works for a single branch, but how would I list all branches with the commits ahead/behind count?

Comment: You can [fetch all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches) and then get the information for each branch.

Comment: @flaxel yes, but I don't want to have to type a command for each branch. I'd like to issue a single command that lists all branches with the commit offsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads/ --format='%(refname:short)' |
while read branch; do
    echo -n "$branch: "
    git rev-list --left-right --count master..$branch
done
```

Docs:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list

Comment: can you help me make this into a git alias? I tried `list = ! git for-each-ref refs/heads/ --format='%(refname:short)' | while read branch; do; echo -n "$branch: "; git rev-list --left-right --count master..$branch; done` 

But I get this error `$ git list` `git for-each-ref refs/heads/ --format='%(refname:short)' | while read branch: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: I think due to the amount of code and its complexity it is better to write a shell script, not git alias.