# cut in ZSH doesn't cut git output from a subshell

Tags: git, zsh, cut

Context: I'm making a shell function to output `git rev-list` information in a more human-friendly way (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433867/git-ahead-behind-info-between-master-and-branch)).

But I'm blocked on unexpected behavior that I can't explain. Here's an illustration:

```sh
REVLIST="$(git rev-list --left-right --count main...fix/preview-data)"

# just to check what the variable contains
$echo \"$REVLIST\" # outputs "57     0"

# This is the unexpected behavior: cut didn't work
echo $(echo "$REVLIST" | cut -d " " -f 6) commits ahead.
# This prints: 57 0 commits ahead. It should print 0 commits ahead.
# note also the single space between 57 and 0. In the echo above there are 5 spaces.
```

I tried replicating this without git in the subshell, then it works as expected:

```sh
REVLIST="$(echo "57     0")"
echo $(echo "$REVLIST" | cut -d " " -f 6) commits ahead.
# this prints as expected: 0 commits ahead.
```

I tried adding/removing quotes to echo commands and variable assignments. I also tried using the `<<<` operator instead of piping, e.g. `cut -d " " -f 6 <<< "$REVLIST"`. Those attempts didn't work.

I'm not sure where this goes wrong or how to make it run as expected. Is it the subshell? Is it the git output? Am I using echo/piping incorrectly?

I'm using ZSH with version 5.7.1.

**Update: additional context**

To answer KamilCuk's on this question:

```
REVLIST="$(git rev-list --left-right --count main...fix/preview-data)"
echo "$REVLIST" | hexdump -C

this prints:

00000000  35 37 09 30 0a                                    |57.0.|
00000005

REVLIST="$(echo "57     0")"
echo "$REVLIST" | hexdump -C

this prints:

00000000  35 37 20 20 20 20 20 30  0a                       |57     0.|
00000009
```

Comment: I guess this could be explained if the string would be along `"      0\r57"` (or something more complicated). Please post the output of `echo "$REVLIST" | hexdump -C`.

Comment: Hey @KamilCuk, thanks for your reply. I added the output of the command that you requested in both cases. I see there are indeed differences, but I'm not yet familiar enough with internal string representations & hexes to interpret the output.

Comment: `09` is a tab, not a space

Comment: Ah.. that probably explains things. I'll try to cut on a tab delimiter instead. Strange that it manifests in the terminal as spaces when I copy-paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output has a tab, not 6 spaces.

Just

```
cut -f2 <<<"$REVLIST"
```

The default separator for `cut` is tab.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I just verified that it is a tab, and cutting on a tab fixes the problem. My confusion came from the tab being displayed as multiple spaces in my VSCode terminal, at least when I copy-pasted the output to use as a variable assignment. I'll remember `hexdump` for the future!