# Simulate repo being behind

Tags: git

I'm working on a script that monitors a repository by running a `git status` and searching for the text "Your branch is behind". If it finds it, it pulls the changes and does a build.

It seems to work well, but it's not super easy to test. I have tested with a test repo where I just edit a text file from another machine and push it, but now I want to test end-to-end with the real code.

Is there any way to put my local repo folder in a state that would simulate a status result of "Your branch is behind"? I tried checkout of a previous commit hash but then I just get a detached head.

Comment: Seems like a fragile approach. What if Git's message changes? I'd look into [hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) instead.

Comment: To do this without parsing Git's human-intended text, you can use `git rev-list --left-right` as in [git ahead/behind info between master and branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20433867/1426891).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just checking out a previous commit (i.e. move `HEAD` to that commit), but leaving the branch pointer where it is, thus entering detached HEAD state, actually move the branch pointer to the previous commit as well:

Before:

```
$ git checkout mybranch
```

```
origin/mybranch → C ← mybranch ← HEAD
                  ↓
                  B
                  ↓
                  A
```

```
$ git reset --hard A
```

After:

```
origin/mybranch → C
                  ↓
                  B
                  ↓
                  A ← mybranch ← HEAD
```

Which is the same situation as if your local branch was on commit `A` to begin with and you fetched new commits `B` and `C` from remote `origin`.