# Show branch status after switching

Tags: git

When I `git switch foo` I would like to know if I need to rebase it onto `master`. Is there any way to make `git switch foo` check if `foo` is behind `master` and print a message like

```
Current branch foo is up to date.
```

or

```
Current branch foo is 6 commits behind `master`
```

after it has switched? Ideally I run the exact same command - `git switch` (so it doesn't mess up my muscle memory when working on different systems) and it only runs when I actually do `git switch` - anything that runs on every prompt will be too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. First you can use the post-checkout commit to run after `git switch`:

```
touch .git/hooks/post-checkout
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-checkout
```

And then in that file you can use this code to print a useful message:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

git rev-list --left-right --count master...HEAD | awk '{print "Behind "$1" - Ahead "$2""}'
```

([Credit for that last command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59391521/265521))

Example output:

```
git switch -
Updating files: 100% (1459/1459), done.
Switched to branch 'fix_warning_message'
Behind 0 - Ahead 2
```

Comment: Note that when Git switches branch names, it automatically does this for whatever the new branch's *upstream* is. But usually you want the upstream of branch `xyz` to be `origin/xyz`, not `master`, so having the post-checkout hook do this separately for `master` is probably the way to go. You might want to augment your post-checkout hook though: sometimes you're not actually switching anything, just extracting some file(s), and post-checkout gets a flag argument for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Git status command.

In my personal opinion, Git status is one of the best git command that will tell you about ahead/behind count for the current branch.

Its usage is simple,

*$ git status*

If you want to learn more about Git commands, you can find a list of git commands here on one page - https://acompiler.com/git-commands/

Comment: The point was to do it automatically. Also `git status` is quite slow on large repos because it has to walk all the files.